# IntValue isn't increasing, when cloning (Roblox Studio)

Tags: integer, roblox, cloning

I have a strawberry field, where I want everyone to have their own strawberries spawn in. I'm trying to make it, so only 10 strawberries can be on the field at once. I've set it up so everytime a strawberry is cloned from ReplicatedStorage, it gets put into Workspace and the IntValue which is the child of the cloning LocalScript will be increased by +1. Cloning process will go on until the IntValue value is 10. When a player picks up a strawberry, the IntValue will decrease by -1, letting a new strawberry spawn in. The problem is, everything works except the IntValue increasing by +1. That means that the IntValue will reach the negatives and the strawberries will spawn in forever.
Local cloning script in StarterPlayerScripts:

```
local remoteEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.StrawberryCollect
local strawberryTemplate = game.ReplicatedStorage.Fruits.Strawberry

local function createStrawberryForPlayer()
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local inventory = player:FindFirstChild("Inventory")

    if inventory then
        local strawberryCount = script.FruitAmount

        if not strawberryCount or (strawberryCount and strawberryCount.Value < 10) then
            local newStrawberry = strawberryTemplate:Clone()
            newStrawberry.Parent = game.Workspace.Fruit.OnTheGround
            newStrawberry.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(-163.146, -137.78), 2.5, math.random(-77.756, 8.488))

            newStrawberry.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
                local character = otherPart.Parent

                if character and character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                    game.Workspace.SoundPack.Pickup:Play()
                    remoteEvent:FireServer(player)
                    newStrawberry:Destroy()

                    strawberryCount.Value = strawberryCount.Value + 1
                end
            end)
        end
    end
end

local function initialSpawn()
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local strawberryCount = script.FruitAmount

    if not strawberryCount then
        strawberryCount = Instance.new("IntValue")
        strawberryCount.Name = "FruitAmount"
        strawberryCount.Parent = script
    end

    strawberryCount.Value += 1
    createStrawberryForPlayer()
    while true do
        wait(math.random(10, 12))
        createStrawberryForPlayer()
    end
end

initialSpawn()
```

The serverscriptserive script, that decreases the IntValue Value by -1:

```
local event = game.ReplicatedStorage.StrawberryCollect

event.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
    game.StarterPlayer.StarterPlayerScripts["StrawberrySpawner3.0"].FruitAmount.Value -= 1
    plr.Inventory.Strawberries.Value += 1
end)
```

Any suggestions or explanations are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```js
while true do
    wait(math.random(10, 12))
    if #workspace.Fruit.OnTheGround:GetChildren()==10 then continue end
    createStrawberryForPlayer()
end
```